# Memory leak with UIImage method "drawInRect"

Tags: ios, memory, uiimage, drawinrect

I have question about correct using UIImage and method drawInRect.

I use iPad 4,Xcode Version `6.1.1`, IOS `8.1.2` and I used ARC and I have tried without ARC

So, I have image "1.jpg".

**Image Properties:**

**Dimension:** 7500 x 8871 pixels

**Resolution:** 72 pixels/inch

**Color Space:** RGB

**Alpha Channel:** NO

I need to rescale the original image "1.jpg"

I use this code:

```
UIImage *originalImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"];
CGSize newSize=(CGSizeMake(4096, 4096));
originalImage=[self GetScaledImage : originalImage andSize: newSize];
```

//----Scaling Method----------------------//

```
-(UIImage *) GetScaledImage :(UIImage *) inputImage andSize :(CGSize) inputSize
{

 UIImage *newImage=[[[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:inputImage.CGImage] autorelease];    
 if (newImage)
 {        
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(inputSize);
     [newImage drawInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, inputSize.width, inputSize.height)];
     newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
 }

 return newImage;
}
```

**My question:**

if I use newSize: (4096, 4096)

```
UIImage *originalImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"];
CGSize newSize=(CGSizeMake(4096, 4096));
```

**Memory now:** 3.1 MB

```
originalImage=[self GetScaledImage : originalImage andSize: newSize];
```

**Memory now:** 4.3 MB

and it works correct

**but** if I use newSize: (3000, 4096)

I have this:

```
UIImage *originalImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"];
CGSize newSize=(CGSizeMake(3000, 4096));
```

**Memory now:** 3.1 MB

```
originalImage=[self GetScaledImage : originalImage andSize: newSize];
```

**Memory now:** 52 MB

and it works incorrect

**and magic**: if I use newSize: (4096,3000) it works correct too **but** (3000,4096) works incorrect

So, my question: How does it work?

Comment: In what way does it work incorrectly?  Does the scaled image look wrong when drawn to the screen, does your app crash or what have you.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem by using the following method instead.

```
+ (UIImage *)scaleImageWithData:(NSData *)data withSize:(CGSize)size
                          scale:(CGFloat)scale
                    orientation:(UIImageOrientation)orientation {
    CGFloat maxPixelSize = MAX(size.width, size.height);
    CGImageSourceRef sourceRef = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)data, nil);
    NSDictionary *options = @{(__bridge id)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways:(__bridge id)kCFBooleanTrue,
                              (__bridge id)kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:maxPixelSize]
                              };
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(sourceRef, 0, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)options);
    UIImage *resultImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:scale orientation:orientation];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CFRelease(sourceRef);
    
    return resultImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there is no magic. The CGImage object is not deallocated but owned. For this, you need to set image.CGImage to some variable and then release it with

CFRelease(cgImage);

Also try to clear graphics context after all processing done.